# Xubuntu 12.04: Use unity-greeter and set user background automatically

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, unity-greeter

on a fresh Xubuntu 12.04 Installation i have set `greeter-session=unity-greeter` in

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.
```

Also I have installed `unity-greeter gnome-settings-daemon`.

Now I want to change the behavior of unity-greeter to what it does in a vanilla Ubuntu:
Change the wallpaper in the greeter to the user-wallpaper.

Comment: This has an answer which likely is helpful; I recommend *against* considering this abandoned and closing.

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm not sure this is a duplicate. The OP wants to use dynamic switching, but the other Q only addresses manual changes.

Comment: Markus: I would imagine this would work automatically. What is the background set to once you install it?

Comment: @Seth You do realize that this question is from 2012 and that its author was last seen around two years ago... ;-)

Comment: @Byte Yes, yes I do. However it is a relatively easy question to test.